# Instagram changes the video URLs every few days?

Tags: php, curl, instagram

Just found a strange happening with Instagram video.

I'm building a social network site on localhost that pulls in users data from their other social feeds and displays it. One of these external sites is Instagram.

Up until yesterday everything was working fine, both photos and videos were displaying perfectly, but since yesterday all direct video urls (.mp4) that had been previously stored in my db are now void, rendering player mime-type errors.

Any new videos scraped in the last 48 hours are still working fine.

Is this standard Instagram practice to change the media file urls every couple of days or is this something that they've just started doing?

This is how I'm CURLing the user data by using the old `?__a=1` trick and not using their API :

```
$url = 'https://www.instagram.com/'.$instaName.'/?__a=1';
```

I grab the content url of any video posts like this :

```
if ($node->is_video == true) {

                $video = scrapeVideoMetaTag($content_url);
                $image = "";

              } else {

                $video = "";
            }
```

And this the function to scrape the meta tags for the actual .mp4 media file URL :

```
function scrapeVideoMetaTag($url)
{

     $site_html =  file_get_contents($url);
     $matches = null;
     preg_match_all('~<\s*meta\s+property="(og:[^"]+)"\s+content="([^"]*)~i', $site_html,$matches);
     $ogtags = array();

     for($i=0;$i<count($matches[1]);$i++) {

         $ogtags[$matches[1][$i]]=$matches[2][$i];

     }

     if($ogtags) {

       if ($ogtags['og:video:secure_url']) {

           $video = $ogtags['og:video:secure_url'];
           return $video;
       }
     }

       $video = "";
       return $video;

}
```

After which I save it to my db.

Does this mean Instagram have locked this down or am I only just noticing this now and this is how they've done stuff for a while?

Comment: Show an example url which used to work, maybe your just forgetting the p `https://www.instagram.com/p/ID/?__a=1`

Comment: Here you go - I now get URL signature expired  : https://instagram.flhr2-2.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/18385e9c2fccc5f401a4a2106a4dd18f/5A4DBA50/t50.2886-16/26188915_1939906679603411_5972116071916765184_n.mp4
This was working fine this morning.

Comment: Like https://www.instagram.com/p/BdfY1NaBvvN/?__a=1 scrape that based on the ID, then grab video_url

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/rivastarr/?__a=1

Comment: Okay so they are constantly changing the cache on the cdn, that figures, so I just have to rescrape the feeds once a day or so, but why are they only changing the CDN url of video files and not photos?

Comment: Yeah the link above grab the json from that then use video `code` to query say, https://www.instagram.com/p/BddGhcrlMHX/?__a=1 notice the p, and then grab the video_url for the video, really you shouldn't need to store anything, downloading the files will just fill your server for no reason other then to store them. Think about using the API though, else you may find your server IP blocked.

Comment: Yeah you were correct, they are changing the URL's on the CDN. I just re-scraped the media url data and it's all working again. The reason I'm storing  the results is two fold. 1) The calls for that JSON data are pretty sluggish, on the site I render the data from the stored values in the database which only rescrapes the JSON for updated likes etc once an hour, but I wasn't rescraping the media url. 

2) I have given users the ability to hide any content pulled into my site if they choose, so need a database to handle that.